# How do I change the default external text editor in psql?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, psql

I want to change the external editor in `psql`. But the command `select-editor` does not work. How can I change it? How do I run the command?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 3):

There are environmental variables you can set, from [`man psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT)

> `PSQL_EDITOR`, `EDITOR`, `VISUAL`
>
> Editor used by the `\e`, `\ef`, and `\ev` commands. These variables are examined in the order listed; the first that is set is used.
>
> The built-in default editors are vi on Unix systems and notepad.exe on Windows systems.

The `PSQL_EDITOR` is if you want to specify a unique editor for just PostgreSQL. You can probably ignore that as not many people have a different editor for that, but in the event you're using a SQL Editor, go for it.

[On Linux, you probably want to change `EDITOR`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42726/3285). On Ubuntu and Debian, that's done like this,

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```